# Large CSV/text processing in Linux

Tags: python, bash, csv, awk, sed

I have a collection of fairly large CSV files (~1M records per, 15MB+) whose contents I need to extract, reformat and then append to a template text file.

I've written the following python script to do this and it does what I want, but runs very slowly (processing took ~15 mins for a single file) and I have several thousand CSV files to process.

The script I wrote is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import shutil as s
from datetime import datetime as dt


dir = '/media/E/data/idb/'
f = '20020401.csv'
outFile = 'importbase.txt'


df = pd.read_csv(dir + f)
df["DataDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DataDate"]).view('int64') 
df["Expiration"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Expiration"], format='%m/%d/%Y')

df["measurement"] = ['options' for t in range(len(df))]
lines = [str(df["measurement"][d])
        + ",type=options"
        + " " 
        + "ticker=" + str(df["UnderlyingSymbol"][d])
        + ",symbol=" + str(df["OptionSymbol"][d])
        + ",expDate=" + str(df["Expiration"][d])
        + ",cont=" + str(df["Type"][d])
        + ",price=" + str(df["UnderlyingPrice"][d])
        + ",strike=" + str(df["Strike"][d])
        + ",last=" + str(df["Last"][d])
        + ",bid=" + str(df["Bid"][d])
        + ",ask=" + str(df["Ask"][d])
        + ",volume=" + str(df["Volume"][d])
        + ",OI=" + str(df["OpenInterest"][d])
        + ",IV=" + str(df["IV"][d])
        + ",delta=" + str(df["Delta"][d])
        + ",gamma=" + str(df["Gamma"][d])
        + ",theta=" + str(df["Theta"][d])
        + ",vega=" + str(df["Vega"][d])
        + ",aka=" + str(df["AKA"][d])
        + " " + str(df["DataDate"][d]) for d in range(len(df))]


a = s.copyfile(dir + outFile, dir + 'import.txt')               
file = open(a, 'a+')
for item in lines:
        file.write("%s\n" % item)
file.close()
```

The `importbase.txt` file is the template file.  I need to append my data to its contents, and then save that as `import.txt` for processing.  Samples of importbase, import and my CSV below:

**importbase.txt**

```
# DDL
CREATE DATABASE import

# DML
# CONTEXT-DATABASE: import
```

**import.txt**

```
# DDL
CREATE DATABASE import

# DML
# CONTEXT-DATABASE: import
options,type=options ticker=A,symbol=A020420C00015000,expDate=2002-04-20 00:00:00,cont=call,price=36.53,strike=15.0,last=0.0,bid=21.0,ask=22.3,volume=0,OI=0,IV=0.6145,delta=0.9987,gamma=0.0,theta=0.6848,vega=0.0aka=ADC 1017619200000000000
options,type=options ticker=A,symbol=A020420P00015000,expDate=2002-04-20 00:00:00,cont=put,price=36.53,strike=15.0,last=0.0,bid=0.0,ask=0.1,volume=0,OI=0,IV=0.5964,delta=0.0,gamma=0.0,theta=0.0,vega=0.0aka=APC 1017619200000000000
options,type=options ticker=A,symbol=A020420C00017500,expDate=2002-04-20 00:00:00,cont=call,price=36.53,strike=17.5,last=0.0,bid=18.7,ask=19.5,volume=0,OI=0,IV=0.6145,delta=0.9987,gamma=0.0,theta=0.6371,vega=0.0aka=ADW 1017619200000000000
options,type=options ticker=A,symbol=A020420P00017500,expDate=2002-04-20 00:00:00,cont=put,price=36.53,strike=17.5,last=0.0,bid=0.0,ask=0.1,volume=0,OI=0,IV=0.5964,delta=0.0,gamma=0.0,theta=0.0,vega=0.0aka=APW 1017619200000000000
```

**20020401.csv**

```
UnderlyingSymbol,UnderlyingPrice,Exchange,OptionSymbol,OptionExt,Type,Expiration,DataDate,Strike,Last,Bid,Ask,Volume,OpenInterest,IV,Delta,Gamma,Theta,Vega,AKA
A,36.53,*,A020420C00015000,,call,04/20/2002,04/01/2002,15,0,21,22.3,0,0,0.6145,0.9987,0,0.6848,0,ADC
A,36.53,*,A020420P00015000,,put,04/20/2002,04/01/2002,15,0,0,0.1,0,0,0.5964,0,0,0,0,APC
A,36.53,*,A020420C00017500,,call,04/20/2002,04/01/2002,17.5,0,18.7,19.5,0,0,0.6145,0.9987,0,0.6371,0,ADW
A,36.53,*,A020420P00017500,,put,04/20/2002,04/01/2002,17.5,0,0,0.1,0,0,0.5964,0,0,0,0,APW
A,36.53,*,A020420C00020000,,call,04/20/2002,04/01/2002,20,0,16.2,17,0,0,0.6145,0.9987,0,0.5882,0.0002,ADD
A,36.53,*,A020420P00020000,,put,04/20/2002,04/01/2002,20,0,0,0.1,0,0,0.5964,0,0,-0.0006,0.0001,APD
A,36.53,*,A020420C00022500,,call,04/20/2002,04/01/2002,22.5,5.7,13.7,14.5,0,5,0.6145,0.9985,0.0001,0.5092,0.0053,ADX
A,36.53,*,A020420P00022500,,put,04/20/2002,04/01/2002,22.5,0,0,0.1,0,1545,0.5964,-0.0001,0.0001,-0.0214,0.0036,APX
A,36.53,*,A020420C00025000,,call,04/20/2002,04/01/2002,25,11.6,11.2,12,0,545,0.6145,0.9963,0.0015,0.1189,0.0612,ADE
A,36.53,*,A020420P00025000,,put,04/20/2002,04/01/2002,25,0,0,0.1,0,882,0.5964,-0.0019,0.0012,-0.2882,0.0485,APE
A,36.53,*,A020420C00030000,,call,04/20/2002,04/01/2002,30,6.5,6.4,6.9,80,2357,0.6145,0.9314,0.0259,-6.1328,1.0651,ADF
```

I use bash a fair amount but wonder if something like sed or awk may be better suited to a lower level task like this where processing time is likely to be a concern.  Any guidance on approach is appreciated.

Comment: You're asking a yes/no question and the answer is simply "yes".

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, any guidance on how to go about it?

Comment: Looks like a good bit of conditional processing for each line which means any sort of OS-level looping construct is going to be slow ("Duh!" ?) I'd probably look at an `awk` solution, or if the *csv files have a delimiter (eg, >>tab<<) possibly upload to a database for processing; I'm guessing a `perl` solution could be fast (and I'm surprised a `python` solution is so slow)

Comment: for a `awk` solution, and assuming delimited input, it looks like you've got 19 fields; some (relatively) simple logic would allow for reformatting the inputs into the desired output, and a single `printf` (with the desired format string) should be all that's need to generate the output

Comment: Consider doing files in parallel and then concatenating the results.  This will cut down on your clock time.

Comment: In your code and example output I m missing a `,` before `aka`:  `+ "aka=" + str(df["AKA"][d])`. Not an answer, but maybe a bug.

Comment: yeah, parallel processing of the CSV files would help, but the current rate of ~15 mins/file is way too slow for a measly 1M-lines/15MB-data; the biggest bang-for-the-buck is going to come from getting the single file processing time down to something more reasonable ... and then adding parallel processing would be the cherry on the top :-)

Comment: @markp-fuso, I'd originally loaded to MySQL, processing moved quickly initially (15s per file) but got bogged down toward the end once cache wasn't readily available (100s per file).  Doing this in part to see if loading to a different DBMS might be an option

Comment: @WalterA, you're correct, updated.  Wasn't causing an issue at this point, but would have when I tried to use it. Thanks

Comment: @Chris my MySQL experience has been limited to functional query testing on a fiddle, but sounds like a problem with either MySQL or the process ... since an increase in volumes shouldn't be that big of an issue for a database (especially if processing each file separately)

Comment: [warning: I don't 'know' Python so fwiw] is the current process building an array (or list) of all 1M lines before printing to the output file? if so, have you tried writing each line to the output file as you build said line (and eliminate the array/list)?  I'm wondering if there could be an issue with how python is allocating memory (eg, each successive line takes a little longer for memory allocation; you see this kind of thing with processes that continually append to the end of a string ... search to end of string, add new data, search to end of (longer) string, add more data)

Comment: @markp-fuso, that makes sense intuitively. Going to test a few versions (re answer below) and see how it affects performance.

Comment: Can you share some example input as text? I would rather not have to share an answer without checking if it actually works ;)

Comment: [edit] your question to show concise, testable, **textual** sample input and output that demonstrates your problem and gives us something we can test against so we can try to help you.

Comment: @AMC, tried to originally, but defaulted to an image (think it was because it was coming from CSV).  I've edited to include a sample in text form.

Comment: Are you open to benchmarking solutions, or should I do so myself? How large are the files? I was thinking of simply repeating the sample CSV to make a file large enough.

Comment: Another thing, is the `OptionExt` column not used? Also, I edited the formatting of the data in your post, I hope that's alright.

Comment: @AMC, I included benchmarks for a couple of the solutions in a comment below.  Files to be loaded vary, but some top 100MB.  I exclude OptionExt, that's correct.

Comment: @Chris Alright, I tested with only 1 million lines/rows. I’ll post my code so you can always give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

I hesitate to post this as the answer because its just speculation. But you will likely save time by iterating the dataframe rows and formatting a single string instead of concatenating a bunch of strings.

```
import pandas as pd
import shutil as s
from datetime import datetime as dt

dir = '/media/E/data/idb/'
f = '20020401.csv'
outFile = 'importbase.txt'


df = pd.read_csv(dir + f)
df["DataDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DataDate"]).view('int64') 
df["Expiration"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Expiration"], format='%m/%d/%Y')

df["measurement"] = ['options' for t in range(len(df))]

a = s.copyfile(dir + outFile, dir + 'import.txt')               
with open(a, 'a+') as file:
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        file.write(
            "{measurement},type=options "
            "ticker={UnderlyingSymbol}"
            ",symbol={OptionSymbol}"
            ",expDate={Expiration}"
            ",cont={Type}"
            ",price={UnderlyingPrice}"
            ",strike={Strike}"
            ",last={Last}"
            ",bid={Bid}"
            ",ask={Ask}"
            ",volume={Volume}"
            ",OI={OpenInterest}"
            ",IV={IV}"
            ",delta={Delta}"
            ",gamma={Gamma}"
            ",theta={Theta}"
            ",vega={Vega}"
            ",aka={AKA}"
            " {DataDate}".format_map(row))
```

In fact, there isn't a real advantage to pandas here. You take up a lot of space building the dataframe but everything needs to pass through a python variable for formatting anyway, so just use the regular CSV module

```
import csv
import shutil as s
from datetime import datetime as dt

dir = '/media/E/data/idb/'
f = '20020401.csv'
outFile = 'importbase.txt'

a = s.copyfile(dir + outFile, dir + 'import.txt')               

with open(dir + f) as in_fp, open(a, "a") as out_fp:
    reader = csv.DictReader(in_fp)
    for row in reader:
        # todo: figure out conversions outside pandas
        #row["DataDate"] = ?
        #row["Expiration"] = ? 
        row["measurement"] = "options"
        file.write(
            "{measurement},type=options "
            "ticker={UnderlyingSymbol}"
            ",symbol={OptionSymbol}"
            ",expDate={Expiration}"
            ",cont={Type}"
            ",price={UnderlyingPrice}"
            ",strike={Strike}"
            ",last={Last}"
            ",bid={Bid}"
            ",ask={Ask}"
            ",volume={Volume}"
            ",OI={OpenInterest}"
            ",IV={IV}"
            ",delta={Delta}"
            ",gamma={Gamma}"
            ",theta={Theta}"
            ",vega={Vega}"
            ",aka={AKA}"
            " {DataDate}".format_map(row))
```

Comment: Wow.  Agree conceptually (simply wrote it to 'work' last night), running the three versions (my original, your edit, and then the second edit) performance difference was pretty significant:  .5 minutes, .45 minutes, .02 minutes.  (Occurs to me I was doing other processing last night which was causing much of the slow down to the original).

Comment: @Chris - glad to hear that most of that 15 minutes was other processing. I was imaging you feeding floppy disks into your pentium PC. I thought the csv module would be faster, but that's impressive. pandas is great if you never have to touch the table values individually, but once you do, you pay the python object construction price.

Comment: Don't suppose you're familiar with `awk` (or something similarly low-level) and think it'd be worth the effort of trying to use it to improve things still?  I'll eventually need to run this over ~4400 files in total.

Comment: @Chris You should be able to improve the performance of the Pandas version by using something like `itertuples()`, `iterrows()` is notoriously sluggish.

Comment: In fact I think [`DataFrame.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html#pandas-dataframe-to-dict) would be even better all around.

Comment: @Chris - I'm not an awk expert. I searched "use awk to split a csv" and got some promising hits so I think its possible. 4400 files with one finished every 10 seconds is about 8 hours. I think i'd add a bit of multiprocessing to this solution, grab a cup of coffee and a good book and call it good.

Comment: @AMC thanks for the suggestions. I don't know pandas iteration as well as I should.

Comment: and for parallel/multi-processing, consider the disk subsystem; a spinning disk will quickly introduce a bottleneck for multiple processes trying to read/write the same disk at the same time; SSDs are better, RAIDs and flash drives even better ... and then there's the idea of reading from one disk/SSD/RAID and writing to another disk/SSD/RAID

Comment: @markp-fuso, agreed, unfortunately SSD isn't an option here (don't have sufficient space on my SSD HD, so this is all running off an external HD.  If you have thoughts about parallelizing some manner of the python script above, I'd welcome input though.

Comment: @Chris  my thoughts on parallel ops consist of running copies of your process in parallel, but in light of your disk setup (especially if that external HD is a spinning disk) I doubt you'll be able to implement much in terms of parallel ops before you hit IO delays; processing files in batches so that you're only hitting a disk with all-reads or all-writes may help, something like: read first X files from HD + write to SSD, mv X files from SSD to HD, read next X files from HD + write to SSD, mv X files from SSD to HD; alternatively, get a 2nd ext/HD and 'stream' from 1st HD to 2nd HD

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with awk, but you're better off with a CSV parser and, since you're using Python already, using it better is probably the answer.

The meat of your problem is to reproduce the CSV as a comma-separated list of name-value pairs.  For that, this will do the job, and I would expect it to perform pretty well.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import csv

fieldnames = ('type', 'ticker', 'symbol', 'expDate', 'cont',
                  'price', 'strike', 'last', 'bid', 'ask', 'volume',
                  'OI', 'IV', 'delta', 'gamma',
                  'UnderlyingSymbol', 'UnderlyingPrice', 'Exchange',
                  'OptionSymbol', 'OptionExt', 'Type', 'Expiration', 'DataDate',
                  'Strike', 'Last', 'Bid', 'Ask', 'Volume',
                  'OpenInterest', 'IV', 'Delta', 'Gamma', 'Theta', 'Vega', 'AKA')

with open('input.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    rows = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)
    for i, row in enumerate(rows):
        if i == 0:
            continue
        line = ','.join( [ '%s=%s' % (k,v) for k,v in row.items() ] )
        print( 'options,%s' % line )
```

producing output:

```
$ ./convert.py | nl
     1  options,type=    A,ticker=36.53,symbol=*,expDate=A020420P00015000,cont=,price=put,strike=04/20/2002,last=04/01/2002,bid=15,ask=0,volume=0,OI=0.1,IV=None,delta=0,gamma=0.5964,UnderlyingSymbol=0,UnderlyingPrice=0,Exchange=0,OptionSymbol=0,OptionExt=APC,Type=None,Expiration=None,DataDate=None,Strike=None,Last=None,Bid=None,Ask=None,Volume=None,OpenInterest=None,Delta=None,Gamma=None,Theta=None,Vega=None,AKA=None
     2  options,type=    A,ticker=36.53,symbol=*,expDate=A020420C00017500,cont=,price=call,strike=04/20/2002,last=04/01/2002,bid=17.5,ask=0,volume=18.7,OI=19.5,IV=None,delta=0,gamma=0.6145,UnderlyingSymbol=0.9987,UnderlyingPrice=0,Exchange=0.6371,OptionSymbol=0,OptionExt=ADW,Type=None,Expiration=None,DataDate=None,Strike=None,Last=None,Bid=None,Ask=None,Volume=None,OpenInterest=None,Delta=None,Gamma=None,Theta=None,Vega=None,AKA=None
     3  options,type=    A,ticker=36.53,symbol=*,expDate=A020420P00017500,cont=,price=put,strike=04/20/2002,last=04/01/2002,bid=17.5,ask=0,volume=0,OI=0.1,IV=None,delta=0,gamma=0.5964,UnderlyingSymbol=0,UnderlyingPrice=0,Exchange=0,OptionSymbol=0,OptionExt=APW,Type=None,Expiration=None,DataDate=None,Strike=None,Last=None,Bid=None,Ask=None,Volume=None,OpenInterest=None,Delta=None,Gamma=None,Theta=None,Vega=None,AKA=None
     4  options,type=    A,ticker=36.53,symbol=*,expDate=A020420C00020000,cont=,price=call,strike=04/20/2002,last=04/01/2002,bid=20,ask=0,volume=16.2,OI=17,IV=None,delta=0,gamma=0.6145,UnderlyingSymbol=0.9987,UnderlyingPrice=0,Exchange=0.5882,OptionSymbol=0.0002,OptionExt=ADD,Type=None,Expiration=None,DataDate=None,Strike=None,Last=None,Bid=None,Ask=None,Volume=None,OpenInterest=None,Delta=None,Gamma=None,Theta=None,Vega=None,AKA=None
```

Comment: Hi, I've edited to include input as text above.  No comma before `ticker` in the output is intentional, not an error.

Comment: Does your "CSV file" not have commas?  How is it delimited?  (I see the need for the name dictionary now.  You can get the same effect by supplying a fieldnames parameter to csv.DictReader.)

Comment: Not sure I follow.  Commas are included in the input file sample above.

Comment: Gotcha.  I guess there was a page-refresh problem on my end.  I updated my answer to match.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @Chris _No comma before `ticker` in the output is intentional, not an error._ That's just strange, what is going to be reading these files?

Comment: @AMC, These are inputs specified for influxdb.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do the conversion in awk (using GNU awk for mktime()):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    n = split("                                         \
                ticker          UnderlyingSymbol        \
                symbol          OptionSymbol            \
                expDate         Expiration              \
                cont            Type                    \
                price           UnderlyingPrice         \
                strike          Strike                  \
                last            Last                    \
                bid             Bid                     \
                ask             Ask                     \
                volume          Volume                  \
                OI              OpenInterest            \
                IV              IV                      \
                delta           Delta                   \
                gamma           Gamma                   \
                theta           Theta                   \
                vega            Vega                    \
                aka             AKA                     \
                DataDate        DataDate                \
        ", outInNameMap)

    for (i=1; i<n; i+=2) {
        outFldName = outInNameMap[i]
        inFldName  = outInNameMap[i+1]
        inNames2outNrs[inFldName]   = ++numOutFlds
        outNrs2outNames[numOutFlds] = outFldName
    }

    dateFmt["expDate"]  = "iso8601"
    dateFmt["DataDate"] = "epoch"

    FS=OFS=","
}

FNR == 1 {
    for (inFldNr=1; inFldNr<=NF; inFldNr++) {
        inFldName = $inFldNr
        outFldNr  = inNames2outNrs[inFldName]
        outNrs2inNrs[outFldNr] = inFldNr
    }
    next
}

{
    printf "options,type=options"
    for (outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numOutFlds; outFldNr++) {
        outFldName = outNrs2outNames[outFldNr]
        inFldNr = outNrs2inNrs[outFldNr]
        fldVal  = $inFldNr
        if ( outFldName in dateFmt) {
            split(fldVal,d,"/")
            if ( dateFmt[outFldName] == "iso8601" ) {
                fldVal = sprintf("%s-%s-%s 00:00:00", d[3], d[1], d[2])
            }
            else if ( dateFmt[outFldName] == "epoch" ) {
                fldVal = mktime(sprintf("%s %s %s 00 00 00", d[3], d[1], d[2]))
            }
        }
        pfx = (outFldNr==numOutFlds ? " " : (outFldNr>1 ? OFS : " ") outFldName "=")
        printf "%s%s", pfx, fldVal
    }
    print ""
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file.csv
options,type=options ticker=A,symbol=A020420C00015000,expDate=2002-04-20 00:00:00,cont=call,price=36.53,strike=15,last=0,bid=21,ask=22.3,volume=0,OI=0,IV=0.6145,delta=0.9987,gamma=0,theta=0.6848,vega=0,aka=ADC 1017640800
options,type=options ticker=A,symbol=A020420P00015000,expDate=2002-04-20 00:00:00,cont=put,price=36.53,strike=15,last=0,bid=0,ask=0.1,volume=0,OI=0,IV=0.5964,delta=0,gamma=0,theta=0,vega=0,aka=APC 1017640800
options,type=options ticker=A,symbol=A020420C00017500,expDate=2002-04-20 00:00:00,cont=call,price=36.53,strike=17.5,last=0,bid=18.7,ask=19.5,volume=0,OI=0,IV=0.6145,delta=0.9987,gamma=0,theta=0.6371,vega=0,aka=ADW 1017640800
options,type=options ticker=A,symbol=A020420P00017500,expDate=2002-04-20 00:00:00,cont=put,price=36.53,strike=17.5,last=0,bid=0,ask=0.1,volume=0,OI=0,IV=0.5964,delta=0,gamma=0,theta=0,vega=0,aka=APW 1017640800
options,type=options ticker=A,symbol=A020420C00020000,expDate=2002-04-20 00:00:00,cont=call,price=36.53,strike=20,last=0,bid=16.2,ask=17,volume=0,OI=0,IV=0.6145,delta=0.9987,gamma=0,theta=0.5882,vega=0.0002,aka=ADD 1017640800
options,type=options ticker=A,symbol=A020420P00020000,expDate=2002-04-20 00:00:00,cont=put,price=36.53,strike=20,last=0,bid=0,ask=0.1,volume=0,OI=0,IV=0.5964,delta=0,gamma=0,theta=-0.0006,vega=0.0001,aka=APD 1017640800
options,type=options ticker=A,symbol=A020420C00022500,expDate=2002-04-20 00:00:00,cont=call,price=36.53,strike=22.5,last=5.7,bid=13.7,ask=14.5,volume=0,OI=5,IV=0.6145,delta=0.9985,gamma=0.0001,theta=0.5092,vega=0.0053,aka=ADX 1017640800
options,type=options ticker=A,symbol=A020420P00022500,expDate=2002-04-20 00:00:00,cont=put,price=36.53,strike=22.5,last=0,bid=0,ask=0.1,volume=0,OI=1545,IV=0.5964,delta=-0.0001,gamma=0.0001,theta=-0.0214,vega=0.0036,aka=APX 1017640800
options,type=options ticker=A,symbol=A020420C00025000,expDate=2002-04-20 00:00:00,cont=call,price=36.53,strike=25,last=11.6,bid=11.2,ask=12,volume=0,OI=545,IV=0.6145,delta=0.9963,gamma=0.0015,theta=0.1189,vega=0.0612,aka=ADE 1017640800
options,type=options ticker=A,symbol=A020420P00025000,expDate=2002-04-20 00:00:00,cont=put,price=36.53,strike=25,last=0,bid=0,ask=0.1,volume=0,OI=882,IV=0.5964,delta=-0.0019,gamma=0.0012,theta=-0.2882,vega=0.0485,aka=APE 1017640800
options,type=options ticker=A,symbol=A020420C00030000,expDate=2002-04-20 00:00:00,cont=call,price=36.53,strike=30,last=6.5,bid=6.4,ask=6.9,volume=80,OI=2357,IV=0.6145,delta=0.9314,gamma=0.0259,theta=-6.1328,vega=1.0651,aka=ADF 1017640800
```

I'm not exactly sure what that final value on your output lines is, it seems to be some variation of seconds since the epoch but I'll leave it as an exercise for you to fix that if necessary. I used more temporary variables than necessary and used clear names for all of them so it'd be obvious what's happening and so wouldn't need commenting to explain it and you should be able to build on it easily.